# Create newline character when third column in file is not unique

Tags: bash

I have a tab-separated file with the following format:

```
January Jay RESERVED    4
February    Jay RESERVED    5
March   Jay SUBMITTED   6
December    Jay USED    7
```

What I would like to do is create spaces, or new lines between the lines where the third column is unique.

For this example, I would like this output:

```
January Jay RESERVED    4
February    Jay RESERVED    5

March   Jay SUBMITTED   6

December    Jay USED    7
```

Comment: Awk can read tab delimited tables, and output them comma delimited.

Comment: You can cut and paste tabs into SO. It's a browser thing.

Comment: Are you looking for unique values, or are these all grouped and you just want a blank line before a new section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in a file called stuff:

```
lastVal="";cat stuff |while read i ; do thisVal=$(echo "$i" |cut -d$'\t' -f'3'); if [ "$lastVal" != "$thisVal" ]; then echo "" ;lastVal=$thisVal; fi ;echo "$i" ;done
```

Here's a version of the same command that you can use as a script. See usage below.

```
#!/bin/bash
lastVal="";
while read i ; do
    thisVal=$(echo "$i" |cut -d$'\t' -f'3')
    if [ "$lastVal" != "$thisVal" ]; then
        echo ""
        lastVal=$thisVal
    fi
    echo "$i"
done
```

If you name the script myScript.bash, you can use it one of these two ways:

```
cat yourfile | /path/to/myScript.bash
```

or

```
/path/to/MyScript.bash < yourfile
```

Note that if you want to insert a literal tab at the Bash prompt, you can enter ctrl+v and then hit tab. Ctrl+v lets you insert other special chars too. Ctrl+v lets you enter special chars like tab, so to add TAB as the delimiter in the cut -d' part, hit ctrl-v then hit tab (that's in Linux, not SO).

Comment: this puts a space in between every line

Answer (score 0):

Awk can do this quite handily:

```
awk -F $'\t' '{print (v==$3 ? $0 : "\n"$0); v=$3}' foo.txt
```

`awk` is designed to work with whitespace-separated columns of data, so the third column is represented by `$3`. All we do is check if the value has changed, and `print` an extra line.

This doesn't check for "unique" values, but only a change in the value from the previous line. From what I can tell, that's the same thing as the answer you accepted.

Comment: If you added -F$'\t' I think they'd have exactly the same behavior. Without that, the awk answer works fine for reservations made by 'Jay', but not for 'Mary Kate' since it uses $IFS, which includes space.

Comment: Good point, there's no harm in explicitly stating FS for tab separated values.